# Ubuntu 18.04 with OKI C301dn

Tags: drivers, printing, ghostscript

The driver seems to have problems converting to PostScript.
Any ideas?

From error_log:

```
D [23/Oct/2018:22:25:52 +0200] [Job 309] Started filter pstops (PID 24589)
D [23/Oct/2018:22:25:52 +0200] [Job 309] Unable to execute pstops program: No such file or directory
D [23/Oct/2018:22:25:52 +0200] [Job 309] PID 24589 (pstops) stopped with status 1!
D [23/Oct/2018:22:25:52 +0200] [Job 309] GPL Ghostscript 9.25: ERROR: ioerror (-12) on closing ps2write device.
```

Comment: This driver should work: http://foo2hiperc.rkkda.com/

Comment: This is exactly the driver that I use.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself:

I removed ghostscript with apt-get. I copied the displayed list of all packages which are removed automatically by removing ghostscript.

```
sudo apt-get remove ghostscript
```

After that: Autoremove surplus packages.

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then I installed the copied list of packages (this also causes installation of ghostscript again).
On my installation it looked like that:

```
sudo apt-get install cups cups-filters ghostscript ghostscript-x printer-driver-pnm2ppa printer-driver-ptouch printer-driver-sag-gdi scribus ubuntu-desktop
```

Old printer entry removed, new printer added --> Everything works fine.